# Change port in azure sql server

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

1. Is there any option to change the lising port in azure sql server ?
2. Is there any log in azure sql server ?

Thks for helpers

Comment: I wouldn't have thought so. Isn't the point of Azure (or at least one of the points) that the highest level unit you work with is the database - the server(s) where that database resides is purposely hidden from you, as are any server level details.

Comment: You can enable audit logs in Azure .. what kind of log you are looking? You cannot configure ports in Azure and you shouldn't assume the ports are fixed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot change the port in Azure SQL Server. Your database is hosted on load balanced cloud server instances which are out of 'customer' control. If you require the service to be presented on another port, one option is to create a VM that performs the NAT/port-remapping for you - but I'd question the wisdom.

If I had to guess, I'd assume you're trying to bypass an IT policy to try and work with a cloud solution, and your infrastructure team have elected to block the port for SQL? Safety first. ;)

Comment: the point i want that it becuase some isp of my clients that open for them just the port 23