# unable to load data in azure sql using azure databricks

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am new to azure databricks . I have written a sample spark program in scala to load in azure sql via below query . I am getting an error . can someone please help me in this

Error Message ----
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host b63da5ce2d2d.tr27.northeurope1-a.worker.database.windows.net, port 65535 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall."

Scala code -

import com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.Configimportcom.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.connect._// Aquire a DataFrame collection (val collection)valconfig=Config(Map("url"->"mysqlserver.database.windows.net","databaseName"->"MyDatabase","dbTable"->"dbo.Clients""user"->"username","password"->"xxxxxxxx"))importorg.apache.spark.sql.SaveModecollection.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).sqlDB(config)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the firewall enabled on the SQL DB. Try disabling that first to confirm the problem.

If it works then you have two choices if you want the firewall enabled:

1) vnet attach your databricks and sqldb to the same vnet. https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html

2) on the sqldb whitelist all the azure ips for the location you are. These are available for download. Note that some locations have more than 128 which is the maximum number of firewall rules available. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=41653

Comment: Hi Simon Thanks for taking your time and replying . I tried disabling the firewall and running the notebook . I got the same error .

Comment: Hi , I was unable to load data in azure sql by fallowing instruction written in azure databricks . I used spark data reader and datawriter and used sql server jdbc driver. I placed the url of azure sql . I am now able to load data in azure sql . I believe that something is misleading in azure databricks documentation .

Answer (score 0):

Why your port number is "65535" not 1433?

SQL Database communicates over port 1433. I think this is the reason why you can not connect to the Azure SQL DB.
[image]

Please reference: [Server-level IP firewall rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-server-level-firewall-rule).

We cannot change the port in Azure SQL Server. Your database is hosted on load balanced cloud server instances which are out of 'customer' control.

Reference: [Change port in azure sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31694129/change-port-in-azure-sql-server).

Port 1433 is the only port that must be open on your desktop computer that hosts your SQL Database client application.

If you don't how to open the port 1433 on your computer,

please see: [How To Open Firewall Port 1433 for SQL Server Database Engine](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/danstolts/2011/06/how-to-open-firewall-port-1433-for-sql-server-database-engine-for-use-with-scom-or-anything-else/).

About how to load data in Azure SQL Database, Azure provides many methods.

1. [Load data from CSV into Azure SQL Database (flat files)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-load-from-csv-with-bcp).
2. [Loading files from Azure Blob storage into Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/preview-loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-sql-database/).

For more details, you can see [Load data into SQL Server or Azure SQL Database with SQL Server Integration Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-sql-database-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017).

Both of them can help you load data in Azure SQL Database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Lean , Thanks for your response . I had tried with default port 1433 as well . However it didnt work . By the way  , i am fallowing the instruction written on page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector under heading "Write data to Azure SQL Database or SQL Server"

Comment: Yeah, I know. But according your error message, it mostly caused by the Azure SQL Server firewall. See my update. Do you sure you have opened the port 1433 on your desktop computer?

Comment: Thanks for your detail input . I am using Azure SQL DB and not on premise sql server . one option that i can think of is creating a virtual machine in azure which will host the sql sever and i will open/check the default port . However , hosting a VM on azure is costly . So i have ruled out that option . I am searching how can load data in azure sql db but have no luck till now . are you able to fallow me?

Comment: You mean you want to load data in Azure SQL DB, and what's your data source? There are two ways can help you do that, load data from flat file and load from Azure cloud. See my update.

Comment: The source is csv files  in blob storage . I am processing the data using spark data bricks . once the data is processed i am inserting the records in azure sql db . i am able to process the data as per requirement but unable to load it . I have fallowed the instruction written in below page under header "Write data to Azure SQL Database or SQL Server"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector.com

Comment: Sorry, I can't open the link. For this question, I suggest you can post an another question and show our the error msg，then others or me can help you with more details. I hope my answer helped you, thanks for your question and have a good day.

Comment: Hi Leon , Thanks for your patience and your time . I have been brainstorming by myself .  I copied public ip address of two VM and added in azure sql firewall setting . These VM's were created automatically when i had created databricks instance . After updating firewall setting in Azure sql , i ran notebook and got same error message

Comment: error message is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host b63da5ce2d2d.tr27.northeurope1-a.worker.database.windows.net, port 65535 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Comment: I have used connection URL as per Microsoft documentation i.e. mysqlserver.database.windows.net .
This is mentioned in below page under heading "Write data to Azure SQL Database or SQL Server"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-spark-connector

Comment: Did you see that: no matter Azure databricks or Spark connector, the error all point to the firewall. There must be some error happend with you Azure SQL DB firewall settings. For a test, can you connect to your Azure SQL database with SSMS successfully?

Comment: Yes ofcourse , i can connect   server and its database from ssms installed in my machine . for that i have to add ip address of machine which has ssms installed in it . similarly i have to add ip address of vm on which spark program is running . i had tried this as explained but i had not luck .

Comment: I'm so sorry that I don't have any good ideas either now. For this blob, could you please mark my answer or vote it? Thanks and have a good day.